# Testing for significance of survey responses

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

I've made these two graphs in ggplot from raw survey data.

```
ggplot(ball, aes(x= VisBea,  group=gender)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = gender), stat="count",position="dodge") +
labs(y = "Percent of Respondents", fill="Observed Gender", x="Visit Frequency")+
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)+ scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Live here","Every day", "Several times a week","Once a week","Several times a month","Once a month","Several times a year","Once a year","Less than once a year")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + scale_fill_discrete(name="Observed Gender",breaks=c("0", "1","2"),labels=c("Unknown", "Male", "Female"))
```

What code would I use to test which answers choices are significant?

Comment: That depends immensely on what you mean by "significant". What test do you want to run (chi squared seems a likely choice)? This probably fits better as a straight statistics question, rather than an R question.

Comment: Perhaps the `survey` package would provide a good framework https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf . Also please `dput()` the data.